# how to add large number of entries in a set

Tags: java, set

I am required to add a very large number of elements in a set.I was thinking of the following implementation

```
Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>(){{
  add("name1");
  add("name2e");
  //and so on
}};
```

or create the set uninitialized and then add values

```
Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>();
myset.add("name1");
//amd so on
```

But i have more than 1000 entries and it it is not feasible for me to add them manually one by one.Is it possible to add a large group as a whole and not one by one?

Comment: you could externalize those values to some properties file and write a little code to read it from there and populate to `Set`

Comment: Where are you getting those values from?

Comment: Your question is unclear, if you have 1000 values then SOMEPLACE you will need to have those values recorded. Either in code, in a file, database, etc, etc.

Comment: @JohnB The entries are in a file

Comment: Can you add an excerpt from the file?

Comment: @user2561865 If the values are from a file, you should use a loop to read each value one at a time and add them to the `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have duplicate values you can't use `set` here. put your all values to file and read them using java code.

then it will easy. You can use code like following to do that

```
    FileReader file=new FileReader("D:\\Test.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);
    String str;
    Set<String> st=new HashSet<String>();
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
         st.add(str);
    }
```

Comment: Being paranoid, I would trim the words.

Comment: If you know there will be 1000+ entries, initialize it like this `Set<String> st = new HashSet<>(1000);`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should use a loop somehow.  Go like this:

```
for (String element : elements) {
    set.add(element);
}
```

It's up to you to figure out how to get the `elements`.  Read them from a file or something.  If the file looked like this:

> name1
>
> name2
>
> name3

Just read each line and for each line add that to your set.

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't a good idea. Its too wierd:

```
Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>(){{
  add("name1");
  add("name2e");
  //and so on
}};
```

- The outer set of braces create an anonymous inner class. `HashSet` isn't final so it works.
- The inner set of braces is an initializer block. Not a static one (which is more commonly used) but an instance initializer block.
- The java code inside there calls the `add()` method on that instance.

But you could do this:

```
String[] strs = new String[]{
  "name1",
  "name2e",
  //and so on
};

Set<String> myset = new HashSet<String>();
myset.addAll(Arrays.asList(strs)); // This is the easy way
```

But this is what I had before @nachokk pointed out the improvement.

```
for (String s ; strs) {
    myset.add(s);
}
```

Its pretty easy to take a file of words that someone gives you and load it into a word processor or text editor. Then use search and replace to reformat it so there is one word per line. Then add a double-quote to the front of each line and a double-quote + comma to the end. Something like TextPad, for example, can do regular expression searches for one whole line and add the chars to the front and end.

That can be cut and pasted into the Java code above.

Comment: or `myset = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(strs));`

Comment: @nachokk Duh. I'm only going to fix it because your code isn't quite right but you deserve the credit for such an obvious bit of code.

Comment: is not bad my code i think, is a constructor injection and diamond inference (Java 7) , and your foreach loop is with `:` instead of `;`

Comment: whys is a doublebrace initialization illegal?

Comment: The doublebrace would mean there is an array inside an array. I added some other comments about what's not legal and what's not interesting.

Comment: @LeeMeador: Actually, the double-brace syntax is completely legal.  It creates an anonymous inner class, then calls `add()` in an initializer block.

Comment: @SLaks That's so obscure you should be flogged for using it. :) I see it though.